# Java LocalConnection Client

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, amf, localconnection

I'd like to connect a Flash Player instance (AMF3) to a Java LocalConnection. I know how to implement the AMF3 spec, since I've done a lot of work with Red5, but I'm unsure how to navigate building the actual LocalConnection interface. There is C code provided [here](http://osflash.org/localconnection), but I can't speak C to save my life. Does anyone know of a Java implementation of the Flash Player LocalConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash local connection use [Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Memory) (see http://osflash.org/localconnection)

To use that in Java, (I suppose) you need write a [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) Wrapper to read it.

The other (easier) solution, is create a socket server (your Java Application) where the client (Flash Application) communicate with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful to you, but there is a project called the merapi project that bridges between adobe air and java, not sure if you could adopt this for a flash player stand alone. See what you think.

[Merapi Project](http://www.merapiproject.net/)